# AES or other encryption implementation on AWS F1

Tags: amazon-ec2, fpga, xilinx

Hi i saw some AES encryption supported in the Github's SDAccel/Vitis docs [here][1]. Is there any way to implement AES encryption or others using the HDK flow. Notably, I'm interested in hardware support for cryptographic suites or operations.

AI was told to simply create a standard HLS project. Just make sure to select "xcvu9p-flgb2104-2-i" as the targeted part.

For instance, here is a sample HLS script to run the hello world (vadd) example:

open_project prj -reset
set_top vadd
open_solution "solution"
add_files ./src/vadd.cpp -cflags "-g -I./src "
set_part xcvu9p-flgb2104-2-i
create_clock -period 250.000000MHz
set_clock_uncertainty 27.000000%
config_interface -m_axi_addr64
config_interface -default_slave_interface s_axilite
config_export -format ip_catalog -ipname vadd
csynth_design
export_design
exit

If you put the above in a file called vadd.tcl, you can then run "vitis_hls -f vadd.tcl" from the hello world example directory. After that, the generated RTL (or the generated Vivado IP) can be used in the HDK flow.

From here I'm not sure how to take the Vivado generated IP zip and include it in the simple hello_world_vhdl HDK example